# LinkedIn member profile plugin isn't working

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to use LinkedIn [member profile plugin](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile), but didn't get lucky in making it working reliably.

The issue is that without any visible reason (as far as I can tell) sometimes it's working and displaying profile card (with or without me being logged in into linked in), but sometimes it makes requests behind the scene but displays nothing.

I've noticed though, if I don't have open LinkedIn session, most likely it will fail to display. In case I logged in before, it shows my profile most of the times, but sometimes fails as well. In documentation they didn't say anything about requirement of having an open session, so I assume it should work the same way for all the cases.

To test it I created a simple html file, in a body of which I put a code generated on Linkedin website. See a plunker below as an example of code. I run it on local webserver under http or https, trying different domains, the same thing.

I noticed when result is unsuccessful one of the responses looks like that:

[image]

Example of code I'm running:

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/pTDwZ0fV3hn8k6Ds

Comment: So the issue is that sometimes you have to login to see the profile and sometimes you don't have to login to see the profile?

Comment: I updated the question, but basically yes: without any visible reason (as far as I can tell) sometimes it's working and displaying profile card (with or without me being logged in into linked in), but sometimes it makes requests behind the scene but displays nothing.

Comment: This might just be an inherent rule for LinkedIn.  If you search for a LinkedIn profile on Google and click on it sometimes you are taken to the profile and sometimes you are asked to login to see the profile.  If you are logged in then you always see the profile.

Comment: Presuming you never found a solution to this? I've just encountered the same thing.

Comment: Not really, as @slaphshot33324 pointed out it's inconsistency from the LinkedIn side.